# Dynamic add of a row in a table with the possibility to add a cell's content in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django-forms, dynamic-tables

Been trying to have this table to dynamically add a row using the button 'addrow' and in the first cell there should be a 'delete' button in all cells except for the first one in the table, i'm working with a django form, the code is a total mess for the moment trying to figure out the right methods first, but yeah here is my html:

```
<table class="interface-table" id="interface-table">
                    <tr class="row-interfaces main-table-header">
                        <th colspan="2" class="head-row"></th>
                        <th colspan="5" class="head-row">a</th>
                        <th colspan="5" class="head-row">b</th>
                        <th colspan="5" class="head-row">c</th>
                        <th colspan="5" class="head-row">d</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row-interfaces secondary-table-header">
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1">Delete</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1">e</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1">f</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">g</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">h</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="sz-3">i</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">j</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1">k</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">l</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">m</th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="sz-3">n</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2">o</th>
                    </tr>

                    {% for form in ipforms %}
                    <tr id="new-row" class="row-interfaces secondary-table-header">
                        {% if not forloop.first %}
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1" id="col0">
                            <button type="button" class="btn delete-btn remove_row" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>
                        </th>
                        {% else %}
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1"></th>
                        {% endif %}
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1" id="col1"> {{form.e}} </th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1" id="col2">{{form.f}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col3">{{form.g}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col4"></th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="sz-3" id="col5">{{form.i}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col6">{{form.j}}</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="sz-1" id="col7">{{form.k}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col8">{{form.l}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col9"></th>
                        <th colspan="3" class="sz-3" id="col10">{{form.n}}</th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="sz-2" id="col11">{{form.o}}</th>

                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

I tried this for my js script :

```
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("interface-table");
    var newRow = document.getElementById("new-row").cloneNode(true);
 
    newRow.removeAttribute("id");
    var deleteCell = newRow.querySelector(".sz-1");
    deleteCell = document.getElementById("col0").innerHTML;
    table.appendChild(newRow);

}

function deleteRow(button) {
    var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

the problem is all the rows get added without the delete button ( it's like with duplicating it always counts as the first row) and it gets added after i apply the form, have been trying a lot of ways (copying cell by cell, jquery that's not my strongest spot) but it just doesn't work, if you guys can hint me at this that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use css, depending on how you setup your first/extra rows, eg: `tr.row-interfaces.secondary-table-header:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1) button { display:none; }`  https://jsfiddle.net/7xqnwp6c/  They'll probably be better ways to setup your classes, but this works with what you've provided.

Comment: Note: IDs must be unique.  If you ever find yourself with code such as `for .. <tr id="new-row">...` then the IDs will not be unique.

Comment: So `.getElementById("new-row")` will *always* get *only* the first row, similar for `document.getElementById("col0")` will always get only the first `col0` (the one in the template)